# Solve the system of equalities and inequalities

Tags: equation-solving, system-variables

I have a system of expressions, in which each expression is an equality or inequality expression of the following form:

- Var = Var1 + Var2
- Var $\odot$ number
- Var $\odot$ Var1
- $\odot$ = $\leq | \geq | == | > | <$

I want to find the range of values for each variable, is this possible to do that by Mathematica?

**Update example**

I tried with `Reduce` but it didn't work as I expected. For example, 
I tried `Reduce[a == b + c && a >= 2 && b <= 10 && c == 5, {a, b, c}]`, 
it returned `2 <= a <= 15 && b == -5 + a && c == a - b`.

What I expect to get is `2 <= a <= 15 && -3 <= b <= 10 && c == 5`

Thanks,

Comment: `Reduce`?  I'm not sure there's enough information to give a definitive answer.

Comment: `Reduce` does not return what I want. For example, I tried `Reduce[a == b + c && a >= 2 && b <= 10 && c == 5, {a, b, c}]`, it returns `2 <= a <= 15 && b == -5 + a && c == a - b`.  What I expect to get is `2 <= a <= 15 && -3 <= b <= 10 && c == 5`

Comment: Try `Reduce[.., {a, b, c}]`, `Reduce[.., {b, c, a}]`, and `Reduce[.., {c, a, b}]` -- the first inequality in each is what you're after.  Perhaps there's a more efficient way.  If this example is typical, you should consider adding it to your question.  As it is, it's a bit vague.  You could even include a few examples to show the range of problems you wish to deal with.

Comment: Its not the optimal way to solve the problem, I think. Uhm, just updated the example to my question as you suggested.

Comment: It seems that you want the minimal bounding rectangle that is aligned with the axes. For this you can use `Minimize` and Maximize` on the separate variables.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Can you be more specific with the above example?

Comment: I put it in a response. Then realized @Michael E2 had shown the same idea only more concisely, in `boundingBox2`. Gave that response an upvote. Will delete mine in a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps there's a better way than using `Reduce` three times, but it seems to me that the computations to figure out the range of each variable will have to be done somehow.  `Reduce` does that.  This will work on such simple inequalities as in the OP's example:

```
And @@ (First@Reduce[a == b + c && a >= 2 && b <= 10 && c == 5, #] & /@
    NestList[RotateLeft, {a, b, c}, 2])

 (* 2 <= a <= 15 && -3 <= b <= 10 && c == 5 *)
```

For more complicated cases, one would have to check the `Head` of the result to see if there are cases, indicated by a head of `Or`.  In that case, one would have to take the union of the ranges of each case.

---

With 100 variables the [`CylindricalDecomposition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CylindricalDecomposition.html) returned by `Reduce` will no doubt contain cases.

Here's a more generalized approach.

```
boundingBox[ineq_, vars_] := And @@ Simplify[
   Reduce[ineq, #] & /@ NestList[RotateLeft, vars, 2] //. And[first_, rest_] :> first
   ]

boundingBox[a == b + c && a >= 12 && b <= 10 && c <= 10 && b >= 1 && c >= 1, {a, b, c}]
(* 12 <= a <= 20 && 2 <= b <= 10 && 2 <= c <= 10 *)
```

---

In some fashion, the maximum and minimum values of each variable have to be computed.  `Reduce` does more than that in computing the cylindrical decomposition, so perhaps some time may be saved.  If we can assume that the inequalities are closed, we can try finding the extrema directly.

```
boundingBox2[ineq_, vars_] := 
 And @@ (MinValue[{#, ineq}, vars] <= # <= MaxValue[{#, ineq}, vars] & /@ vars)

boundingBox2[a == b + c && a >= 12 && b <= 10 && c <= 10 && b >= 1 && c >= 1, {a, b, c}]
(* 12 <= a <= 20 && 2 <= b <= 10 && 2 <= c <= 10 *)
```

It's actually faster on this example.

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := 
  Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@  AbsoluteTiming@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

boundingBox[
  a == b + c && a >= 12 && b <= 10 && c <= 10 && b >= 1 && c >= 1, {a, b, c}] // timeAvg
boundingBox2[
  a == b + c && a >= 12 && b <= 10 && c <= 10 && b >= 1 && c >= 1, {a, b, c}] // timeAvg
(* 0.01004385 *)
(* 0.00204969 *)
```

Comment: In my cases, there will be no `Or`, so don't worry about that.

Comment: So in your solution, we still have to call `Reduce` 3 times, right? Since my system of expressions may include up to 100 variables, it will definitely cost the efficiency if we call `Reduce` 100 times...

Comment: I tried your solution with `a == b + c && a >= 12 && b <= 10 && c <= 10 && b >= 1 && c >= 1`, the result is not clean. I expect something like `20 >= a >= 12, 10 >= b >= 2, 10 >= c >= 2`.

Comment: @Loi.Luu That's because the expressions returned by `Reduce` contain `Or`.

Comment: Is there any way to specify all variables as Integer? I don't want to get some result like `1 < a < 2`

Comment: @Loi.Luu According to the documentation, you can specify the domain to be `Integers` for `MinValue` and `MaxValue`.  You could also use `Ceiling` and `Floor` on them.  Finally one can add `&& Element[a, Integers]` to the inequalities.

Comment: @MichealE2 I tested with 300 variables, and it took more than 5 minutes to complete the computation. Is there any other way to improve the performance?

Comment: @Loi.Luu I expected it to be of at least quadratic complexity in the number of variables (or proportional to the number of variables times the number of inequalities).  So 5 min. might be a bit longer than I would have expected if timed on my machine, but not extraordinarily long.  The only optimization idea that comes to mind is to use the bounds found at each step to eliminate the variable from the set of inequalities.  (No easy way to do this comes to mind, but perhaps someone with more time can figure it out.)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the existance statement:

```
Reduce[
       Exists[{#2, #3},
              a == b + c && a >= 2 && b <= 10 && c == 5
             ],
      #1] & @@
  RotateLeft[{a, b, c}, #] & /@ Range[0, 2]
```

> ```
> {2 <= a <= 15, -3 <= b <= 10, c == 5}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

**Backsubstitution** is an option often ignored when people use *Reduce*. In the op's case it gives:

```
  Reduce[a == b + c && a >= 2 && b <= 10 && c == 5, {a, b, c}, Backsubstitution -> True]
  2 <= a <= 15 && b == -5 + a && c == 5
```

The op's writes: *" What I expect to get is `2 <= a <= 15 && -3 <= b <= 10 && c == 5` "*

**Notice** : Mathematica should not produce this outcome because it is not a description of the solution set of the equations inputed. For example, `a==2, b==10, c==5` falls in the range   `2 <= a <= 15 && -3 <= b <= 10 && c == 5`  but it is **not** a solution of the system